# Why would MyBatis sometimes not find the mapper, but most of the time it would?

Tags: java, mybatis

I'm getting a MyBatis error intermittently in a Tomcat web application:

```
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for com.cisco.salesconnect.screport.mapper.hubportfolio.Authorization.getAuthorizedHubSupervisorIds
### Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for com.cisco.salesconnect.screport.mapper.hubportfolio.Authorization.getAuthorizedHubSupervisorIds
    at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:30) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:149) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:140) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
    at com.cisco.salesconnect.screport.dao.SCHubAuthorizationServiceHandler.getAuthorizedHubSupervisorIds(SCHubAuthorizationServiceHandler.java:168) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.cisco.salesconnect.screport.dao.SCHubAuthorizationServiceHandler$7.run(SCHubAuthorizationServiceHandler.java:404) [classes/:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_181]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for com.cisco.salesconnect.screport.mapper.hubportfolio.Authorization.getAuthorizedHubSupervisorIds
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration$StrictMap.get(Configuration.java:964) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.getMappedStatement(Configuration.java:755) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.getMappedStatement(Configuration.java:748) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:146) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
    ... 6 more
```

I could get the error once in the log, then immediately go to the browser and click edit->resend and it would work fine.  I was able to recreate this issue by making setting up a web service runner in Postman and setting it to 10 iterations.

I'm getting the configuration using Java objects and not an XML file.  I used to be sharing a SqlSession object in a multithreaded web request, but no longer am since reading it's not thread safe.  I was also trying to share the Configuration object amongst multiple requests so that it doesn't have to go through the expense of finding the XML mapper files with each request.

What other things should I look for?  I can't post the raw source code for IP reasons, but can post something like it once I know what people are looking for.

Thank you from the Woodsman.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your usage, but in general, you should reuse a `SqlSessionFactory`. `Configuration` is used when building `SqlSessionFactory` and this should be done only once during application startup. Please see the [Getting Started](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/getting-started.html) guide.

Answer (score 1):

`Configuration` object is not thread-safe.

The problem you are facing may be caused by the fact that changes done to `Configuration` object in the thread that configured it are not visible in other threads because such changes are not [safely published](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/#_safe_publication).

So you either need to use configuration per-thread or do make sure that you safely publish you configuration objects.

Comment: Thank you. I saw in the docs that SqlSession was not thread safe, but did not see anything about any other objects.  I'm currently sharing Configuration and Environment.  Are either of these thread safe?

Comment: Also, can I re-use the configuration for subsequent requests in the same thread?