# Mybatis is taking a long time to scan configuration files

Tags: multithreading, mybatis

I'm using myBatis and Java based configuration rather than the XML based configuration.  I wonder if I should switch to XML files.  I do the following to get the SqlSession object:

```
    private Configuration configuration = null; 

    public SqlSession getSqlSession() throws SCExceptions {
        SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(getConfiguration());
        return sqlSessionFactory.openSession();
    }


    private Configuration getConfiguration() throws SCExceptions {
        /**
         * For debugging purposes, allow a -DdoNotReuseConfiguration.  
         * Setting this flag to any value will cause the server to reload the MyBatis
         * mapper files with each request.  If debugging, this allows a change to be made
         * and have the server not need to be restarted.
         */
        String doNotReuseConfiguration = System.getProperty("doNotReuseConfiguration");
        if(this.configuration == null || doNotReuseConfiguration!=null) {
            String environmentName = null;
            if("local-dev-nonjndi".equals(lifeCycle) || "dev".equals(lifeCycle))  {
                environmentName = "dev";
            } else if("local-stage-nonjndi".equals(lifeCycle) || "stage".equals(lifeCycle)) {
                environmentName = "stage";
            } else if("local-prod-nonjndi".equals(lifeCycle) || "prod".equals(lifeCycle)) {
                environmentName = "prod";
            }
            Environment environment = new Environment(environmentName,transactionFactory,getDataSource());
            configuration = new Configuration(environment);
            configuration.addMappers("com.mycompany.mybatis.mapper");
        }
        return this.configuration;
    }
```

I noticed that it takes about 200-300ms for MyBatis to scan the mapper files in the specified package.  To be more efficient, I experimented with creating this Configuration object once by way of a lazy initialization technique.  Then I noticed that sometimes things like a sqlSession.selectOne(...) type query would not find the mapper.  Then sometimes it would.

My problem is that I'm not using any form of dependency injection and am not in a position to introduce it at this point.  All the documents I've seen are catered toward the Spring Boot crowd, and I suspect that it somehow manages MyBatis such that all the initialization is properly handled and done only once, and not on a per call basis like what I have here.

I realize I cannot use SqlSession in a multithreaded environment.  Another poster said I cannot use Configuration in a multithreaded environment.  That poster might be correct, but I could not find anything in the docs to say which MyBatis objects are thread safe.

My question is, which objects can I safely re-use in a multithreaded environment so that I can shave off that Configuration scanning time, or should I switch to an all XML approach?

Comment: Have you read my comment on your former [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58862574/)?

Comment: @ave I'm afraid I missed your comments, but saw Roman Konoval's.  The oversight was unintended.  However, I'm having a hard time reconciling what you both said.  Your answer seems to suggest I can create the configuration object once, and reuse it for all subsequent uses, whereas Roman's seems to suggest it cannot be reused.  Should I use XML instead of Configuration objects?

Comment: I didn't suggest to reuse `Configuration`. I suggested to reuse `SqlSessionFactory`. As explained in the getting started guide, `SqlSessionFactory` is thread safe and you can obtain a new `SqlSession` from it, so you don't have to worry about `Configuration` once you get `SqlSessionFactory`. Parsing configuration is a time-consuming process, so you should not repeat it. It does not matter if you use Java config or XML.